# Disable back fade popup

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, popup

Is it possible to disable the popup backfade?

I tried this:

My popup controller:

```
 var popupInvalid = $ionicPopup.alert({
        templateUrl: 'templates/popup-template-invalid.html',
        cssClass: 'success-popup',
        scope: $scope
    })
```

Sass:

```
.success-popup{
     .backdrop {
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

But I did not succeed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the backdrop is a sibling of `.popup-container`, which then contains your popup. So the only option you have is to globally modify the `.backdrop` class, e.g.:

```
.backdrop
{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Check this example: http://play.ionic.io/app/8f14ab72d922

Unfortunately this influences all other popups in your application as well.

Comment: I had done it that way too but as you said it affects globally and I wanted in just a few popups. But anyway, thank you